# Update SonarQube 3.4.1 to 4.1.2 error [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database without detail

Tags: upgrade, sonarqube

I'm in the process to upgrade SonarQube from version 3.4.1 to 4.1.2 and after many problems regarding plugins update and other issues I got the following error once I go to `http://mySonarQube:9000/setup` and click on Upgrade button:

`[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database`

but without detailed description.

Here the full log (I've shorten it because of limitation):

```
2014.06.05 18:05:08 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:08 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :component_id, {:name=>"issues_component_id"})
2014.06.05 18:05:09 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 1.5520s
2014.06.05 18:05:09 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:09 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :root_component_id, {:name=>"issues_root_component_id"})
2014.06.05 18:05:11 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 1.6070s
2014.06.05 18:05:11 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:11 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :rule_id, {:name=>"issues_rule_id"})
2014.06.05 18:05:13 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 1.7460s
2014.06.05 18:05:13 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:13 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :severity, {:name=>"issues_severity"})
2014.06.05 18:05:15 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 2.1410s
2014.06.05 18:05:15 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:15 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :status, {:name=>"issues_status"})
2014.06.05 18:05:17 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 2.4070s
2014.06.05 18:05:17 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:17 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :resolution, {:name=>"issues_resolution"})
2014.06.05 18:05:20 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 2.4040s
2014.06.05 18:05:20 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:20 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :assignee, {:name=>"issues_assignee"})
2014.06.05 18:05:22 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 2.7400s
2014.06.05 18:05:22 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:22 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :action_plan_key, {:name=>"issues_action_plan_key"})
2014.06.05 18:05:25 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 2.7720s
2014.06.05 18:05:25 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:25 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issues, :issue_creation_date, {:name=>"issues_creation_date"})
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 3.1960s
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MigrateViolationsToIssues: migrated (28.8430s) ============================
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  DeleteReviewWidgets: migrating ============================================
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  DeleteReviewWidgets: migrated (0.0460s) ===================================
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  ReplaceReviewNotifications: migrating =====================================
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  ReplaceReviewNotifications: migrated (0.0060s) ============================
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIndexToSnapshotsRootProjectId: migrating ===============================
2014.06.05 18:05:28 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:snapshots, :root_project_id, {:name=>"snapshots_root_project_id"})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 1.4660s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 12376 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIndexToSnapshotsRootProjectId: migrated (1.4670s) ======================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIndexToGroupRolesRole: migrating =======================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:group_roles, :role, {:name=>"group_roles_role"})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.1010s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 547 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIndexToGroupRolesRole: migrated (0.1030s) ==============================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  UpdateIssuesActionPlanKey: migrating ======================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  UpdateIssuesActionPlanKey: migrated (0.0020s) =============================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddOracleIdTriggers: migrating ============================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddOracleIdTriggers: migrated (0.0000s) ===================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreateIssueFilters: migrating =============================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- create_table(:issue_filters, {})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0420s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issue_filters, :name, {:name=>"issue_filters_name"})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0550s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreateIssueFilters: migrated (0.1000s) ====================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreateIssueFilterFavourites: migrating ====================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- create_table(:issue_filter_favourites, {})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0460s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:issue_filter_favourites, :user_login, {:name=>"issue_filter_favs_user"})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0510s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreateIssueFilterFavourites: migrated (0.0990s) ===========================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddDashboardSharingPermission: migrating ==================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddDashboardSharingPermission: migrated (0.0330s) =========================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddScanAndDryRunPermissions: migrating ====================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddScanAndDryRunPermissions: migrated (0.0290s) ===========================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreatePermissionTemplates: migrating ======================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- create_table(:permission_templates, {})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0420s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreatePermissionTemplates: migrated (0.0430s) =============================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreatePermissionTemplatesUsers: migrating =================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- create_table(:perm_templates_users, {})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0340s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreatePermissionTemplatesUsers: migrated (0.0360s) ========================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreatePermissionTemplatesGroups: migrating ================================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- create_table(:perm_templates_groups, {})
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0380s
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreatePermissionTemplatesGroups: migrated (0.0400s) =======================
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:30 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MigrateDefaultPermissions: migrating ======================================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MigrateDefaultPermissions: migrated (0.3420s) =============================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIndexToRulesPluginRuleKeyAndPluginName: migrating ======================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:rules, [:plugin_rule_key, :plugin_name], {:unique=>true, :name=>"rules_plugin_key_and_name"})
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.1570s
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 2048 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIndexToRulesPluginRuleKeyAndPluginName: migrated (0.1580s) =============
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  RemoveNotificationsCreatedAt: migrating ===================================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- remove_column("notifications", "created_at")
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0430s
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  RemoveNotificationsCreatedAt: migrated (0.0430s) ==========================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MigrateUsersNames: migrating ==============================================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MigrateUsersNames: migrated (0.0280s) =====================================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  FixOracleTriggerNames: migrating ==========================================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  FixOracleTriggerNames: migrated (0.0000s) =================================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIndexToCharacteristicsEnabled: migrating ===============================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:characteristics, :enabled, {:name=>"characteristics_enabled"})
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0870s
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIndexToCharacteristicsEnabled: migrated (0.0880s) ======================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MoveIssuesIdToBigint: migrating ===========================================
2014.06.05 18:05:31 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- execute("ALTER TABLE issues CHANGE id id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT")
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 3.3090s
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- execute("ALTER TABLE issue_changes CHANGE id id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT")
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0630s
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 130 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MoveIssuesIdToBigint: migrated (3.3780s) ==================================
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  ReplaceKeyRegexpByKeySearchInMeasureFiltersData: migrating ================
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  ReplaceKeyRegexpByKeySearchInMeasureFiltersData: migrated (0.0040s) =======
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddProvisioningPermission: migrating ======================================
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddProvisioningPermission: migrated (0.0410s) =============================
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddTechnicalDebtToIssue: migrating ========================================
2014.06.05 18:05:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("issues", "technical_debt", :integer, {:null=>true})
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 3.3810s
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 18397 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddTechnicalDebtToIssue: migrated (3.3830s) ===============================
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  RenameWidgetSqalePyramidToTechnicalDebtPyramid: migrating =================
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  RenameWidgetSqalePyramidToTechnicalDebtPyramid: migrated (0.0070s) ========
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  ResizeTimelineWidgets: migrating ==========================================
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  ResizeTimelineWidgets: migrated (0.0140s) =================================
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddUniqueConstraintToGroupsUsers: migrating ===============================
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- Remove duplications for 0 user group associations
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0000s
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index(:groups_users, [:group_id, :user_id], {:name=>"GROUPS_USERS_UNIQUE", :unique=>true})
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0580s
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 27 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddUniqueConstraintToGroupsUsers: migrated (0.0630s) ======================
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddCharacteristicsColumns: migrating ======================================
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :parent_id, :integer, {:null=>true})
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0790s
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :root_id, :integer, {:null=>true})
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.2400s
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :function_key, :string, {:null=>true, :limit=>100})
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.1570s
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:38 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :factor_value, :decimal, {:null=>true, :precision=>30, :scale=>20})
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0790s
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :factor_unit, :string, {:null=>true, :limit=>100})
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.1120s
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :offset_value, :decimal, {:null=>true, :precision=>30, :scale=>20})
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0800s
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :offset_unit, :string, {:null=>true, :limit=>100})
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0680s
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :created_at, :datetime, {:null=>true})
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0870s
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :updated_at, :datetime, {:null=>true})
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0830s
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 870 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddCharacteristicsColumns: migrated (0.9920s) =============================
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:39 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MigrateCharacteristics: migrating =========================================
2014.06.05 18:05:47 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MigrateCharacteristics: migrated (8.4390s) ================================
2014.06.05 18:05:47 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:47 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddAdministerIssuesPerm: migrating ========================================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddAdministerIssuesPerm: migrated (1.1810s) ===============================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  RemoveUselessCharacteristicsData: migrating ===============================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- remove_column("characteristics", "quality_model_id")
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0840s
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- remove_column("characteristics", "depth")
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0960s
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- remove_column("characteristics", "description")
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0970s
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- drop_table(:characteristic_properties)
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0040s
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- drop_table(:characteristic_edges)
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0040s
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- drop_table(:quality_models)
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0040s
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  RemoveUselessCharacteristicsData: migrated (0.3010s) ======================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddPermTemplateKeyPatternColumn: migrating ================================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("permission_templates", :key_pattern, :string, {:null=>true, :limit=>500})
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0480s
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 2 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddPermTemplateKeyPatternColumn: migrated (0.0480s) =======================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddNetworkUseSubCharacteristic: migrating =================================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddNetworkUseSubCharacteristic: migrated (0.1060s) ========================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIssueChangeCreationDate: migrating =====================================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column("issue_changes", "issue_change_creation_date", :datetime, {:null=>true})
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0630s
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 130 rows
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  AddIssueChangeCreationDate: migrated (0.0640s) ============================
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Start components...
2014.06.05 18:05:49 INFO  [o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector]  Initializing Hibernate
2014.06.05 18:05:50 INFO  [o.s.s.s.SearchIndex]  Starting Elasticsearch...
2014.06.05 18:05:51 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] version[0.90.6], pid[27032], build[e2a24ef/2013-11-04T13:54:09Z]
2014.06.05 18:05:51 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initializing ...
2014.06.05 18:05:53 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initialized
2014.06.05 18:05:53 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] starting ...
2014.06.05 18:05:53 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] started
2014.06.05 18:05:54 INFO  [o.s.s.s.SearchIndex]  Elasticsearch started
2014.06.05 18:05:55 INFO  [o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient]  Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2014.06.05 18:05:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Security realm: LDAP
2014.06.05 18:05:55 INFO  [o.s.p.ldap.LdapRealm]  LdapContextFactory{url=ldap://company.com:389, authentication=simple, factory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, bindDn=, realm=null}
2014.06.05 18:05:55 WARN  [o.s.p.l.LdapGroupMapping]  Properties 'ldap.user.objectClass' and 'ldap.user.loginAttribute' are deprecated and should be replaced by single property 'ldap.user.request' with value: (&(objectClass=organizationalPerson)(userPrincipalName={login}))
2014.06.05 18:05:55 INFO  [o.s.p.ldap.LdapRealm]  LdapUserMapping{baseDn=OU=Users,OU=_Company,DC=adamgis,DC=company,DC=com, request=(&(objectClass=organizationalPerson)(userPrincipalName={0})), realNameAttribute=name, emailAttribute=mail}
2014.06.05 18:05:55 INFO  [o.s.p.ldap.LdapRealm]  Groups will not be synchronized, because property 'ldap.group.baseDn' is empty.
2014.06.05 18:05:55 INFO  [o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory]  Test LDAP connection: OK
2014.06.05 18:05:55 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Security realm started
2014.06.05 18:05:55 INFO  [o.s.s.n.NotificationService]  Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2014.06.05 18:05:55 ERROR [sqale]  No license for plugin sqale
2014.06.05 18:05:56 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]Fail_to_upgrade_database

    java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
    java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
    java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
    org.sonar.plugins.xml.rules.AbstractMessagesRepository.loadMessages(AbstractMessagesRepository.java:143)
    org.sonar.plugins.xml.rules.XmlMessagesRepository.<init>(XmlMessagesRepository.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:620)
    org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:717)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:620)
    org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
    org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
    org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
    org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1033)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1025)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:373)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:163)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
    org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
    org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/05 18:10:40 | TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
2014.06.05 18:10:41 INFO  [o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2014.06.05 18:10:42 INFO  [o.s.s.n.NotificationService]  Notification service stopped
2014.06.05 18:10:42 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] stopping ...
2014.06.05 18:10:42 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] stopped
2014.06.05 18:10:42 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] closing ...
2014.06.05 18:10:42 INFO  [o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] closed
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/05 18:10:43 | 2014.06.05 18:10:43 INFO  Web server is stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/05 18:10:44 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

NOTE: I've addressed sqale plugin license error by eliminating it temporarily but the other error remains.

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration did not fail, only the startup produced this error.

Looks like you're using a version of the XML plugin that is not compatible. Just remove the sonar-xml-plugin.jar file from "extensions/plugins" folder, restart and everything should be fine.

Comment: Yep that solved the problem!!, thanks a lot!!, do you know which xml plugin version is compatible with SonarQube 4.1.2 I couldn't find it.

Comment: Finally I figure it out that 1.2 version of xml plugin is compatible. Thanks.